# How do I set number format with custom Grouping and Decimal separators

Tags: jasper-reports

For example: I have 9999.99 and I want to display 9.999,99 in my report.

I try to set custom pattern is #.##0,00;-#.##0,00 but it does not working

My textfield:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the field and *textField* declaration (the snippet of *jrxml*)?

Comment: You can see in: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xZySo.png

Comment: The text will be better then the screenshot in this case... What is type of `$F{out_balance}` field?

Comment: $F{out_balance} is a BigDecimal

Comment: What version of *JasperReports* (3.x or higher?) and *JDK* are you using?

Comment: You can use sriptlet to have a common solution. Or you can apply the pattern `#,##0.00;#,##0.00-`, for example and use the replace function

Comment: JasperReports 4.0.0
JDK 6

I don't want to display 9,999.99
I want to display 9.999,99 in my report.

Comment: I want to use 1000 separator is '.' not ','

Comment: I've just add the answer with sriptlet solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The work of pattern depends on *Locale* settings. The *Grouping* and *Decimal* separators are defined in *Locale*.

If you want be free of regional (*Locale*) settings you can use this scriptlet:

```java
package utils;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CustomDecimalFormatter {

    public static String format(BigDecimal value, String pattern, char decimalSeparator, char groupingSeparator) {
        DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
        otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(decimalSeparator);
        otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(groupingSeparator);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(pattern, otherSymbols);
        return df.format(value);
    }
}
```

This scriptlet allows to set pattern, custom *Grouping* and *Decimal* separators.

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="format_decimal" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <import value="utils.CustomDecimalFormatter"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT id, cost*100 as cost from product]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="COST" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="50">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="154" height="50"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[The result of using
classical pattern.
Depends on System locale]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="154" y="0" width="191" height="50"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[The result of using the sriptlet]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00;#,##0.00-">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="154" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{COST}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="154" y="0" width="191" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[CustomDecimalFormatter.format($F{COST}, "#,##0.00;#,##0.00-", ',', '.')]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I've set the *Grouping* and *Decimal* separators and the pattern (***`#,##0.00;#,##0.00-`***).

The result will be:

[image]

---

**Note**

Don't forget to add class (jar) with sriptlet to classpath.

Comment: Many thanks!! But its only display in jasper report. When I use OpenERP addons jasper report, it still display separator is ',' Can you help me

Comment: Can you check the work of a sriptlet on the server where *OpenERP* is running? I mean the work of the *CustomDecimalFormatter.format* method

Comment: @Alex K Can you tell me how to add my java class file (CustomDecimalFormatter.java) file in My OpenERP Addons.I want to add in my custom module.